# Webpack разбиение бандла на N файлов

Tags: javascript, webpack

В моем проекте необходимо настроить code splitting и разбить выходной bundle.js, генерируемый вебпаком, на несколько частей. Желательно по критерию размера файла (например по 50кб). С ходу не нашел таких директив для секции *output* в конфиге. Может уже кто-то сталкивался с такой задачей? Секция output в моем конфиге на данный момент выглядит так:

```
output: {
  path: paths.appBuild,
  filename: "static/js/[name].js",
  chunkFilename: "static/js/[name].chunk.js",
  publicPath: publicPath,
  devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info => 
       path.relative(paths.appSrc, info.absoluteResourcePath)
       .replace(/\\/g, "/")
},
```

Comment: CommonChunksPlugin?

Answer (score 0):

Все решается с помощью [AggressiveSplittingPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/aggressive-splitting-plugin/)

```
new webpack.optimize.AggressiveSplittingPlugin({
  minSize: 10000,
  maxSize: 30000
}),
```